# Failure to start a Neptune notebook

Tags: amazon-neptune, graph-notebook

I can't seem to make a neptune notebook, everytime I try I get the following error:

```
Notebook Instance Lifecycle Config 'arn:aws:sagemaker:us-west-2:XXXXXXXX:notebook-instance-lifecycle-config/aws-neptune-tutorial-lc' 
for Notebook Instance 'arn:aws:sagemaker:us-west-2:XXXXXXXXX:notebook-instance/aws-neptune-tutorial' 
took longer than 5 minutes. 
Please check your CloudWatch logs for more details if your Notebook Instance has Internet access.
```

Note that the cloudwatch logs that it suggests to look at don't exist.

The neptune database was created using this cloudformation template: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/blob/master/aws/services/NeptuneDB/Neptune.yaml

Which created the neptune cluster in the default VPC.

The notebook instance was created using this cloudformation template: https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-neptune-customer-samples/neptune-sagemaker/cloudformation-templates/neptune-sagemaker/neptune-sagemaker-nested-stack.json

passing in the relevant values from in for the created neptune stack.

Has anyone seen this type of error and knows how to get over it?

Answer (score 1):

I had to go in and modify the predefined install script used by neptune and add and `nohup` command to the final section of the install as described here https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sagemaker-lifecycle-script-timeout/

Answer (score 0):

Probably what is happening is that your notebook instance does not have access to the internet. Check your NAT configuration for your VPC and their security groups have allowed outbound rules to all